# Mapbox : Add data layer for POIs - transportation, school and retail / grocery stores

Tags: python, mapbox, plotly-dash, mapbox-gl

I am rendering a map using mapbox API and would like to enrich the map by displaying additional location / POI data.

Here's a similar example: https://github.com/patelnisarg61/Toronto-Fatal-Collisions-Analysis/blob/master/collision.py

mock code below:

```
       MAPBOX_KEY = "xxxxx"

       data = []

       data.append({

                    "type": "scattermapbox",
                    "lat": df["Lat"],
                    "lon": df["Long"],
                    "name": "Location",
                    "hovertext": name,
                    "showlegend": False,
                    "hoverinfo": "text",
                    "mode": "markers",
                    "clickmode": "event+select",
 
                    "marker": {
                               "symbol": "circle",
                               "size": 12,
                               "opacity": 0.7,
                               "color": "black"
                              }
                    }
       )

      

    layout = {

                 "autosize": True,
                 "hovermode": "closest",
                 "mapbox": {

                     "accesstoken": MAPBOX_KEY,
                     "bearing": 0,
                     "center": {
                         "lat": layout_lat,
                         "lon": layout_lon
                     },
                     "pitch": 0,
                     "zoom": zoom,
                     "style": "outdoors",

                 },

                 "margin": {
                    "r": 0,
                    "t": 0,
                    "l": 0,
                    "b": 0,
                    "pad": 0
                }

    }
```

How do I add additional POI data such as transit, hospitals, schools and grocery stores using either native mapbox API endpoints or data from other providers such as OSM / Google Maps?

For reference, this data is available via the OSM Feed: https://docs.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/reference/mapbox-streets-v8/

Plotly scattermapbox docs: https://plotly.com/python/reference/#scattermapbox-customdata

Answer (score 1):

I used the example in the [official reference](https://plotly.com/python/scattermapbox/#set-marker-symbols) as a basis, and the data used in the similar question. In this data, the data with bicycles in the 'VEHTYPE' column was extracted and used as the data for the graph. You will need a mapbox access token for this graph. For more information about markers, please refer to [this page](https://labs.mapbox.com/maki-icons/). However, it seems that not all icons can be used.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/patelnisarg61/Toronto-Fatal-Collisions-Analysis/master/Fatal_Collisions.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url, sep=',')

df_bicycle = df[df['VEHTYPE'] == 'Bicycle']

mapbox_access_token = open("./mapbox_api_key.txt").read()

fig = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(
    mode = "markers+text",
    lon = df_bicycle['X'],
    lat = df_bicycle['Y'],
    marker = {'size': 15, 'symbol': ["bicycle"]*len(df_bicycle)},
    text = ["Bicycle"]*len(df_bicycle),
    textposition = "bottom right"))

fig.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    height=600,
    width=1000,
    mapbox=dict(
        accesstoken=mapbox_access_token,
        style="streets",
        center=dict(
            lat=df_bicycle['Y'].mean(),
            lon=df_bicycle['X'].mean()
        ),
        zoom=10, 
        pitch=0),
    showlegend=False)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yep, this helps. However, I am looking for a way to access mapbox / osm POI data as source and part of the question is how to get the data?

Comment: I must have misread that, you want to get OSM point information from Plotly? I've never seen that before, as far as I know. My understanding is that only OSM maps are available as maps from plotly, and that is the basis for the visualization. If my answer interferes with your question, please let me know and I will remove it.

Comment: yeah, basically add a data layer of POIs. If you check out the links, there are examples of using geojson for POI data. 

https://docs.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/reference/mapbox-streets-v8/ 

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-tiling-service/examples/points-of-interest/